# PHP session_name(): Cannot change session name when session is active Error

Tags: php, session, logging

I am getting some unexpected errors on some code which has been working for a few weeks. I haven't changed this code yet I'm getting two errors upon logging in.

> session_name(): Cannot change session name when session is active in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/FantasyKicks/index.php on line 5
>
> session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/FantasyKicks/index.php on line 7

I have tried running session_destroy() to put me back on the login page and delete the session and then taking that line out and logging back in, but both errors still appears. I am wondering if there is actually an issue with how I've coded the logging in process or not.

**login.php** (i've taken out some irrelevant code on this page)

```
session_name('FantasyKicks');

session_start();

if(!$email & !$password) {
        echo "All fields required";
    } else {
        if(!$email) {
            echo "Email required";
        } else {
            if(!$password) {
                echo "Password required";
            } else {
                if($num == 0) {
                    echo "Incorrect email or password";
                } else {
                    // User is logged in
                    echo "LoggedIn";
                    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $user['UserID'];
                    $_SESSION['Email'] = $user['Email'];
                    $_SESSION['FirstName'] = $user['FirstName'];
                    $_SESSION['LastName'] = $user['LastName'];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**index.php** (start of index.php)

```
require 'fkdb.php'; // Connect to database which uses XML config file

session_name('FantasyKicks');

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
   $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the session methods excessively, you should only use `session_start();` once at the top of your code in a controller. If you really have to check if the session is started you can use the code below, but it is best practice to call it once.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

If you are calling it once and it still fails it could be your php configuration.
In php.ini find the following line and set it to false:

```
session.auto_start = false
```

As for the session name, this is just the name of the cookie; `session_name();`
is functionally equivalent to `ini_get('session.name');` so unless you want to change the php configuration, I do not see why you would want to call this method. I would keep the default 'PHPSESSID' as it makes debugging easier.

Comment: Okay, so i've tried setting session.auto_start=false in php.ini (it was  session.auto_start =0 before) and this hasn't worked. I've taken out session name and put that if statement everywhere I've called session_start() except from the index.php file and I'm still getting the error

Comment: Apologies! When the user logs in, I load a separate php file into a div container. I had accidentally placed the index.php file here which was causing it to loop over and over which meant repeating the session_start(). A stupid mistake but one I'm glad I've finally noticed! Thanks for trying to help me in any case, I appreciate it.